# Looping string characters?

Tags: string, abap

How can I read each character in a String? For example, I want to read each character in String "a7m4d0". After that I want to verify that each character is a character or a number. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? If no, why not - if yes, which part did give you problems? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DATA: smth TYPE string VALUE `qwert1yua22sd123bnm,`,
      index TYPE i,
      length TYPE i,
      char  TYPE c,
      num   TYPE i.

length = STRLEN( smth ).

WHILE index < length.
  char = smth+index(1).
  TRY .
      num = char.
      WRITE: / num,'was a number'.
    CATCH cx_sy_conversion_no_number.
      WRITE: / char,'was no number'.
  ENDTRY.
  ADD 1 TO index.
ENDWHILE.
```

Here's your problem solved :P

Comment: Building code around catching exceptions does not look right, still +1

Answer (score 7):

A bit convoluted and on a recent 740 ABAP server.   :)

```
DATA: lv_text  TYPE string  VALUE `a7m4d0`.

DO strlen( lv_text ) TIMES.
  DATA(lv_single) = substring( val = lv_text off = sy-index - 1 len = 1 ) && ` is ` &&
                    COND string( WHEN substring( val = lv_text off = sy-index - 1 len = 1 ) CO '0123456789' THEN 'Numeric'
                                 ELSE                                                                             'Character' ).
  WRITE : / lv_single.
ENDDO.
```

Comment: @tomdemuyt I took me some time to get used to that syntax but I'm on the right path now... "Unfortunately", a large part of SAP new products/tutorials does use this syntax now so it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can access a single character within a string:

This example will extract out the character "t" into the variable "lv_char1".

```
DATA: lv_string TYPE char10,
      lv_char   TYPE char1.

lv_string = "Something";

lv_char1 = lv_string+4(1).
```

Appending "+4" to the string name specifies the offset from the start of the string (in this case 4), and "(1)" specifies the number of characters to pick up.

See the documentation here for more info:

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/Helpdata/EN/fc/eb341a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm

If you want to look at each character in turn, you could get the length of the field using "strlen( )" and do a loop for each character.

Comment: actually, since i just tried to do that, DESCRIBE FIELD doesn't seem to work for strings that well. I tried strings of different (smaller) sizes and the length always seemed to be 8 - weird. What i found was that the builtin function 'strlen' can give you the accurate length of the string.

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is the old-school variant, I prefer `strlen( )`.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: `DESCRIBE FIELD ... LENGTH` will not work with strings at all - it'll produce a syntax error, at least in newer releases. As for C fields, `DESCRIBE FIELD` will tell you the length of the field, not the length of the content!

Comment: @vwegert `DESCRIBE FIELD ... LENGTH IN BYTE MODE` is what I meant. And I'm not sure I understand exactly what you meant by 'C fields'. You mean some kind of fields when interfacing SAP through some kernel add-on? (cuz I wouldn't know about those)

Comment: @vlad-ardelean C fields as in `DATA foo TYPE c`. Byte mode is usually not what you want, btw :-)

Answer (score 2):

One more approach

```
PERFORM analyze_string USING `qwert1yua22sd123bnm,`.

FORM analyze_string USING VALUE(p_string) TYPE string.

  WHILE p_string IS NOT INITIAL.
    IF p_string(1) CA '0123456798'.
      WRITE: /  p_string(1) , 'was a number'.
    ELSE.
      WRITE: /  p_string(1) , 'was no number'.
    ENDIF.
    p_string = p_string+1.
  ENDWHILE.

ENDFORM.
```

No `DATA` statements, string functions or explicit indexing required.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post it's old but this might be useful, this is what use :)

```
  DATA lv_counter TYPE i.

  DO STRLEN( lv_word ) TIMES.

    IF lv_word+lv_counter(1) CA '0123456789'
      "It's a number 
    ENDIF.

    lv_counter = lv_counter + 1.

  ENDDO.
```